# C# WPF 0xC0000005: Access violation

Tags: c#, wpf

While developing a WPF app I encountered this crash.
I tried with/without debugger, Release/Debug configurations, same result.
The message `0xC0000005: Access violation` was shown only in Output window, when I started the app VS appeared to be running it for ~10 seconds, then stopped as if I just closed the app normally, but it never showed.
Disabling Just My Code and enabling Break for every exception didn't help.
I have made no changes to the code, and the day before it ran without a problem.
Re-cloned the git repo, still nothing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There isn't any code from your project that could lead to an answer, nor is there a specific question to be answered. Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question if you need help.

Comment: As said by [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/836721/you-receive-a-0xc0000005-access-violation-error-message) article, it is a memory corruption problem

Comment: @Lithium Because there is no code that this is specific to. This is a problem with WPF (which uses DirectX) and Afterburner (which tries to inject an overlay). Searching for answers using this error code yielded no results that were useful, so I made a self-answered question, for the next person this happens to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was a DirectX overlay app (MSI Afterburner). Turning it off helped.

I went to `Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance\Problem Reports` (or Search for "View all problem reports" in Start), the report said `Fault Module Name: d3d9.dll`, that made me think it could be Afterburner.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this - anyways, it helped me find a problem a customer has. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks but i found 'module unknown'